# Error when use noUiSlider create range by onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I have a simple javascipt:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="max_range(300)">Max 300</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="max_range(1000)">Max 1000</a>
<div id="price"></div>
```

and javascript function:

```
function max_range(max) {
   var price = document.getElementById('price');

    noUiSlider.create(price, {
        connect: true,
        behaviour: 'tap',
        start: [ 0, max ],
        step: 100,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max':  max,
        }
    });
}
// load default
max_range(500);
```

When I catch event onlick. Show this bug `"Error: Slider was already initialized."`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

On every `onclick="max_range(1000)"` you are trying to create a new instance of noUiSlider. It would be working fine for the first time but when you click send time, you get your error `Error: Slider was already initialized.`

All you need is to update your range (min, max) when user click your link.

```
var price = document.getElementById('price');

noUiSlider.create(price, {
    connect: true,
    behaviour: 'tap',
    start: [ 0, 500],
    step: 100,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max':  500, // your default.
    }
});

function max_range(max) {
    // Update range
    price.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': max
        }
    });
    // Set the upper handle,
    // don't change the lower one.
    price.noUiSlider.set([null, max]);
}
```

You can update options using updateOptions method. See [this](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-update) document for more information.

Comment: I want set Range and Start

Comment: @haitruonginfotech I've updated the answer, it now update both range and start.